# changing the titlebar settings(text, color)

Tags: android

I am trying to change color of the WindowsTitlebar. I looked/read around and understood as below(code below in styles.xls added for this change)

```
     <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. --> 

</style>
 <style name="LargeTitleTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dp</item>
   <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/titleTextStyle</item>
   <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="titleTextStyle" >
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>

</style>
<style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">#92D050</item>
</style>
```

And in androidmanifest.xml the rferece to thetheme below

```
 android:theme="@style/LargeTitleTheme">
```

But this does not seem to be working
Not sure where am I going wrong here. Need help here.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for custom title

```
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">#404040</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
```

I got help from this [link](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)

Comment: when I used the code you shared, the color change happens but the app icon and the appname disappear from my title bar.

Comment: I just gave an example .. if you see the link i provided in answer.. you can find a details

Comment: The problem looks to be with the parent attribute for my theme. using parent="AppTheme" shows the icon+name in title but color chage does no show. Using parent="android:Theme" shows color change but icon/appname vanish.

Answer (score 0):

changing parent to parent="android:Theme.light" solved the problem for now